# How to update existing ionic2 project to the 2.1.18 version of ionic2 CLI

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have updated ionic2 CLI from 2.1.17 to 2.1.18, so how should i upgrade my existing project which I have build using 2.1.17 version.

Here is ionic info details -
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Not installed

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.45",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "ionic: An Ionic project"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *Ionic CLI* version is updated. Your project is in **Ionic 2 RC3**( based on `"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",`) not 2.1.7. Your current project should still work.

If you want to upgrade your project to the current RC4 version, the quickest way is to see the package.json file of the  [ionic starter template](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json).
Update your package.json accordingly. Delete your node_modules folder.
Finally run

```
npm install
```

Check [the readme](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#updating-to-200-rc4)

Another way is to simply do,
`ionic start myApp blank --v2` and replace the src folder with yours and add any additional packages you have in your previous project.